# Creating a gotoxy() function without dependencies in C

Tags: c, gcc, portability

Turbo C offered `gotoxy()` function in conio.h but it was not a standard.

I use gcc compiler and need `gotoxy()` function.

I searched online but found only functions which are specific to OS or have some kind of dependency which makes it less portable.

eg: `gotoxy()` function for windows use the Windows API and for linux it uses things like ncurses.

I found a suggestion in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170021/how-could-i-achieve-gotoxy-in-gcc)

which mentions something about setting up a 2-d array, assigning values to cells and plotting.

[image: Screenshot]

When I attempted it, one of the problems was that after a new line has been printed there's no going back without a gotoxy() function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *...found only functions which are specific to OS or have some kind of dependency which makes it less portable.* Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You don't want a dependency? But what do you think depending on `<conio.h>` or TurboC is? For POSIX platforms, if you want advanced textual interfaces then using ncurses *is* the "standard" solution. And it exists Windows ncurses libraries, both emulated in Cygwin/MinGW&MSYS and "native" Windows.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: There's also `pdcurses` on Windows.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg What I meant was that I want the programs using this function to run on both windows and linux. I need it to be portable.

Comment: Then you have two possibilities: Either use some library that exists on all platforms you want to build on (like the curses variants); Or code it up all yourself. I know which solution I would choose.

Comment: Can someone tell me how to code a gotoxy() function by setting up a 2-d array, assigning values to cells and plotting ?

Comment: @J...S There is no way to write such a function portably.  The C language does not standardize the facilities needed to implement such a function.  You *must* depend on platform-specific features or use a third-party library (such as ncurses) that abstracts away platform differences (thereby allowing *your* code to be portable).

Comment: http://www.c-faq.com/osdep/termcap.html

Comment: Do you think existing solution have OS dependencies just to annoy you?

Answer (score 1):

You will always necessarily have dependencies because the nature of console I/O is platform specific.  The purpose of a library such as ncurses is to abstract such platform dependencies to provide a common interface.

[ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) is available for a wide range of platforms including [Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/install.html),